# Pantheon-mail freezes or crashes when using fcitx input method to reply a mail

Tags: pantheon-mail, fcitx

It happens when I try to reply the mail with fcitx input method, it doesn't happens with gcin input method.

My bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-mail/+bug/1661909